# Como criar um app android usando somente c++ no Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++

Somente por questões de aprendizagem, é possível criar um app usando somente c++(sem JNI)?  E se for possível, quais são os passos, tem algum exemplo 'Helloword' em algum lugar?

Pelo que sei algumas coisas em xml serão inevitáveis.(Estou certo?)

Answer (score 3):

Eu achava que não era, mas na verdade é possível sim, desde que seja com a versão 1.3 ou superior.

Você deve ir ao SDK Manager (o próprio do Android Studio) e entrar na aba SDK Tools. Lá você encontrará um pacote com o nome Android NDK, e você deve começar instalando-o. Isso já deve tomar um tempo considerável, graças ao tamanho do pacote.

Como a criação e execução dos apps já é um processo um pouco mais extenso, deixo aqui um link que explica detalhadamente [como iniciar projetos com C++ no Android Studio](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-code-in-an-android-app-with-the-ndk/).

Comment: obrigado! Embora eu esteja atras de c++ puro, sem JNI (eu nem mencionei )

Answer (score -2):

Sem JNI até seria possível mais teria que fazer hacks no sistema operacional do android oque não seria tão simples já que ele é projetado pra ser seguro.

Além do mais a JNI é apenas uma API que disponibiliza algumas funções prontas que normalmente são utilizadas para acesso a hardware, é como você programar para linux, ou outro sistema operacional, você provavelmente vai utilizar algumas bibliotecas padrões como a própria STD do C++ por exemplo e também as bibliotecas de sistema operacional, porém como o kernel do android é projetado pra ser seguro, apesar de ele ser linux-based, você iria precisar reprojetar todas as funcionalidades que seriam utilizadas pelo seu atual hardware, então afinal, pra que reinventar a roda se você já tem todo o acesso ao hardware pronto ?